# Problem with entry point detection as a file offset

Tags: pe, entry-point

I have found problem with finding file offset which actually is program entry point.

In case I experience problem, value of AddressOfEntryPoint is 0x1018. Here is a section which maps this address.

[image: Section header]

I assume entry point should be `0x28 = 0x10 + 0x1018 - 0x1000 (PointerToRawData + AddressOfEntryPoint - VirtualAddress)`

However tools says it is 0x18 instead. I'm not sure why, made some experiments and came up with another formula.

```
0x18 = (0x10 / 0x200) * 0x200 + 0x1018 - 0x1000 ((PointerToRawData / FileAlignment) * FileAlignment + AddressOfEntryPoint - VirtualAddress)
```

I use FileAlignment from OptionalHeader and it works great, however I don't know if it is a coincidence or somewhere documented, so asking here for confirmation.

---

Also, probably not important, but file is packed with UPack(0.399), packer signature BE****AD50FF7634EB7C4801.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to calculate, if you already have the (virtual) address of the entry point, you should just add the base image.

Comment: @Dillinur I want to calculate file offset for EP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE#PointerToRawData --

> if a section's physical start is lower than 200h (the lower limit for
>   standard alignment), it is rounded down to 0.

Thus, the entry point's physical offset would be:
`0x00000018 = 0x00000000 + 0x00001018 - 0x00001000` (PointerToRawData_rounded_down + AddressOfEntryPoint - VirtualAddress)

Comment: Well it should be `0x18` because IDA and DIE says so, also I know packer signature and it is at 0x18, not 0x28. So I think there should be something related to FileAlignment and PointerToRawData values, because msdn says PointerToRawData should be multiple of FileAlignment, however it is not.

Comment: After reading https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE#PointerToRawData, I learned something new and updated my answer above :)

Comment: The section start had to be non-zero in order to be loaded.  I don't remember why we chose 0x10.  Perhaps because that's where the PE signature was, so it looked nice.

Comment: Great, thanks. All I did was rounding down, but I needed verification if it is not a coincidence.

Comment: @peterferrie You don't remember why?? Of topic question, but are you one of those who designed UPack? If so is there any information for unpacking script? I could reverse it, but that info could save some time.

Comment: I contributed to the last ...three? releases - designed the header layout, and supplied the size optimisations.  Yes, it wasn't ideal (I did better with Crinkler).  To reach OEP, break on 4010EB, step, break on EIP+19C, step.  That's it.